# Solving a complicated inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, absolute-value

I have got the following inequality

$|(a_{12}+a_{21}) x_1 - i (a_{12}-a_{21}) x_2 + (a_{11}-a_{22}) x_3 + (a_{11}+a_{21}) X| \le \sqrt{a_{11}^2 + |a_{21}|^2} + \sqrt{a_{22}^2 + |a_{12}|^2}$,

where $a_{12}=a_{21}^*$ are complex conjugates; and $a_{11}$ and $a_{22}$ are real coefficients. Also, $|\vec{x}| + |X|\le 1$. Here $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

Problem: I need to solve for $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $X$.

This is my first question on StackExchange. So please don't mind if you find something wrong in the way I am asking.

Edit: I have rewritten my question in a more simplified form which I just got.

Comment: $\vec{x}=X=0$ is always a solution. If $C_4>0$, then any sufficiently small $\vec{x}$ and $X$ would constitute a solution.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange! As @user1551 pointed out, there are trivial solutions to your inequality. Maybe you need to add some kind of restrictions or requirements to the solution space. Note that you can edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: Are $x_1, x_2, x_3, X$ real, or are they allowed to be complex?

Comment: $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $X$ are real.